# What is difference in `lastModifiedDateTime` and `statusChangedDateTime` in docusign list envelope API?

Tags: docusignapi

I have seen in the envelope status changes API in DocuSign, the lastModifiedDateTime is ahead of the statusChangesDateTime. I was expecting it must be same or in some case `lastModifiedDateTime` may greater than `statusChangesDateTime` when the enveloped is updated.

```
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-10-19T13:54:08.4670000Z",
        "initialSentDateTime": "2021-10-19T13:54:09.0930000Z",
        "sentDateTime": "2021-10-19T14:28:09.9470000Z",
        "statusChangedDateTime": "2021-10-19T14:02:38.4800000Z",
```

I have to use the date in the listEnvelopeStatusChange API so that I will get the latest modified or status changed envelope always...
Can I missing something here? Here is the request I am hitting for getting envelopes list:

GET [https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes?count=10&from_date={statusChangedDateTime}&include=recipients&order_by=status_changed&order=asc&folder_types=normal,inbox,sentitems,draft&status=deleted,completed,created,declined,delivered,processing,sent,signed,timedout,voided&start_position=0](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%7BaccountId%7D/envelopes?count=10&from_date=%7BstatusChangedDateTime%7D&include=recipients&order_by=status_changed&order=asc&folder_types=normal,inbox,sentitems,draft&status=deleted,completed,created,declined,delivered,processing,sent,signed,timedout,voided&start_position=0)

Answer (score 0):

**lastModifiedDateTime** - this is the last time (most recent) the envelope was changed.
**statusChangedDateTime** - this the last time (most recent) the status of the envelope changed.

Not every change is a status change. So it's always possible that **lastModifiedDateTime > statusChangedDateTime** but never the other way around.

(they will be equal if the last change to the envelope was a status change, for example it was sent)

Comment: I was thinking the same but in my case the lastModifiedDateTime is ahead of statusChangeDateTime as you can see in the above response (i.e lastModifiedDateTime < statusChangeDateTime). There I am suspecting why its happening like this?

Comment: Again here I can see the new response:
            ```"createdDateTime": "2021-10-19T14:26:20.0370000Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-10-19T14:27:10.5470000Z",
            "initialSentDateTime": "2021-10-19T14:27:11.2630000Z",
            "sentDateTime": "2021-10-19T14:27:11.2630000Z",
            "statusChangedDateTime": "2021-10-20T04:40:57.9130000Z",```

(lastModifiedDateTime < statusChangesDateTime)

Comment: Do you know how to reproduce this? in theory it's a bug, but maybe there's some reason for this that I can't understand.

Comment: In general I have created an envelope and then just correct that envelope after some time. So whenever I first time created/send envelope there is little difference in timestamp. 
like this:  ``"lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-10-21T04:32:05.1830000Z", "statusChangedDateTime": "2021-10-21T04:32:05.7770000Z"``

But once you corrected the envelope after some time. 
The dateTime fields are:
``"lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-10-21T04:32:05.1830000Z", "statusChangedDateTime": "2021-10-21T04:34:57.8830000Z"``

Comment: Again at last if we have signed that envelope after some time. 
The datetime fields are:  ``"lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-10-21T04:32:05.1830000Z", "statusChangedDateTime": "2021-10-21T04:38:51.0930000Z"``

Comment: What's the status of the envelope?

Comment: Its changing actually in every stage as I am doing different action on single envelope. So whenever I sent an envelope its status is `sent`, when I corrected its again the status is `sent`. And when I signed it its status changed to `completed`.

Comment: It's possible that for some action, like maybe correction, the status change does not trigger a "last modified" update. I would argue it's a bug, but not sure

Comment: Agreed. It may be happening for correction action but I have seen it for signing an envelope action as well. So can I please know what it the best place where I can raise this ?

Comment: I can ask and get back to you

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: not yet, can't get answers yet. Is this blocking your work?

Comment: Yes. Actually I am polling the data based on lastModifiedTime, which is creating issue while polling of data...

Comment: I would suggest to use both and find whichever is latest. I know that's more work, but even if I get an answer and even if this is a bug (which I don't know yet) it will take a while to fix...

Comment: Still in this case we will not getting updates for the older envelope. Any updates on this @Inbar Gazit ?

Comment: Do you mind asking a new question I'm not clear what you're asking